# Matlab: Regular expression: Except: Requires dot '.' at end to function

Tags: regex, matlab

Why does the following regular expression to find all instances EXCEPT `abd` require a dot at the end of the given pattern to function as intended:

```
>> regexp({'abc';'abd'},'^(?!abd$)')
ans =
{
  [1,1] = [](1x0)
  [2,1] = [](1x0)
}

>> regexp({'abc';'abd'},'^(?!abd$).')
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 1
  [2,1] = [](1x0)
}
```

This applies in the simpler case without use of a cell as well:

```
>> regexp('abc','^(?!abd$)')
ans = [](1x0)

>> regexp('abc','^(?!abd$).')
ans = 1
```

Comment: That does not answer your question but `~strcmp({'abc';'abd'},'abd')` could be a better option

Comment: And to answer your question, your regexp check that your string does not start with `abd` and capture the first character (the dot) of any other sequence if the first condition is satisfied. If there is no dot, there is nothing to capture and then all output will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clear after you check the [`regexp` reference page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#expand_panel_body_btn_p45-option) and see that by default, empty matches are not returned.

Note that `^(?!abd$)` pattern is a sequence of two *non-consuming* patterns, a start of string anchor (`^`) and a negative lookahead (`(?!abd$)`) that matches a location in a string that is not immediately followed with `abd` and end of string.

When you add a `.` after the lookahead, you introduce a *consuming* part to the regex, and now it actually matches and consumes any single char, and then the regexp returns a non-empty match.

All you need is to override the default behavior by adding the `emptymatch` option:

```matlab
>> regexp({'abc';'abd'},'^(?!abd$)', 'emptymatch'
)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [2,1] = [](1x0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering to completion.